# Sharing Pre-compiled Headers efficiently

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, precompiled-headers

I have a framework which is being used by several projects (which includes several samples to show how the framework works). The framework has components such as the core, graphics, physics, gui etc. Each one is a separate library. There are several configurations as well.

A main solution file compiles the complete project with all the possible configurations so that the projects can use the libraries. Since the framework is rarely recompiled, especially by someone (including me) working on a project that utilizes the framework, it makes sense to pre-compile the many headers.

Initially I had each project/sample have its own pre-compiled header used for the whole project. Each time I would have to rebuild the same pch (for example, Debug), So I decided that a shared PCH would reduce the redundant PCH compilation. So far so good. I have a project that compiles the PCH along with the libraries. All the subsequent projects/samples are now using the same PCH. This has worked wonderfully.

The only problem is that I have seen an increase in file size. This is not a roadblock, as if a project that uses the framework is intended to be released, it can sever itself from the shared PCH and make its own. I have done this for the sake of rapid development (I have actually created a tool which creates the VS project files and source files for a new project/sample ready to be built as well as facilitate in upgrading a previous project that was using an older version of the framework).

Anyway, (I am presuming that) the increase in file size is because the independant VS project file that is creating the shared PCH is including all the headers from all the libraries. ***My question is whether I can use conditional compilation (#ifndef) to reduce the size of the final executable? Or maybe share multiple PCH files somehow (as far I know though, that is not possible, but I maybe wrong) If I am not making sense, please say so (in kind words :) ) as my knowledge of PCH files is very limited.***

Thanks!

> Note: To re-iterate and make it clear, so far, I have one solution file that is compiling all the libraries including the shared PCH. Now if I recompile all the samples and projects, they compile in a couple of seconds or more at most. Before, each project would recreate a PCH file. Also, initially I wanted a PCH for each library, but then I found out that a source file cannot use multiple PCH files, so this option was not feasible. Another option is to compile all possible combinations of PCH files, but that is too time consuming and cumbersome and error prone.

Comment: PLEASE VOTE FOR THIS: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/4931119-allow-precompiled-headers-to-be-shared-between-pro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the size problem is coming from using headers you don't actually need, but that it still makes sense to use these headers when developing because of the faster turn around.

On **using #ifndefs:** Precompilation is crude.  You lose the ability to share the precompilation work at the point where there is a difference.  If using #ifndefs to make different variants of what you include, I.e. if you have

```
#ifndef FOO
```

Then the precompiled header must stop before the point where FOO is defined differently in two files that use that precompiled header.  So #ifndef is not going to solve the problem.  The net result is that FOO must be the same, or you're back to separate pch files for the different projects.  Neither solves things.

As to **sharing multiple .pch files:** A fundamental limitation of .pch files is that each .obj can only use one.  Of course .pch files can have arbitrary combinations of headers.  You could have a .pch for core+graphics, a .pch for core+physics, core+ai etc.  This would work just dandy if none of the source files needed to 'talk' to more than core+one-module at a time.  That does not sound realistic to me.  Such a scheme and variants on it sound like a lot of restructuring work for no real gain.  You don't want to be building zillions of combinations and keeping track of them all.  It's possible, but it is not going to save you time.

In my view you're doing exactly the right thing by sacrificing executable size for fast turn-around during development/debugging, and then having a slower but leaner way of building for the actual release.

Answer (score 0):

In the past I've found that you quite quickly run into diminishing returns as you put more in the precompiled headers, so if you're trying to put more in to make it more useful in a larger number of projects then it will hit a point that it slows down.  On our projects the PCH files take longer than most source files to compile, but still only a few seconds maximum.  I would suggest making the PCH files specific to each project you are using.  You are right in saying that a source file can only refer to a single PCH file, but one way of getting around this is to use the 'force include' option (in the Advanced tab I think) to ensure that all files include the PCH file for that project.